# How to put HTML tables in an inline-block so that they stay in one row and I only have to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I'd like everything to say on one line even if the row is wider than the width of the screen and if I want to access the later elements I just have to use the scroll of the screen to get righter.

I tried this:

```
CSS:
.sth{
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

It doesn't work, can someone help please? 
Thanks :)

Comment: What is that style to `<tr>`? `<table>`? provide a [mcve] if that's to any table type element, remove the `display:inline-block` property.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are tying to achieve?

```css
div {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```